# Count of entities with a certain field value, filtered by created date

Tags: views

I’ve got users with a gender field and I want to display counts of how many males and females were registered on or before a particular date.  So:

```
COUNT(user.gender=male) and COUNT(user.gender=female) where user.created < {date}.
```

Using views aggregation I can easily get the male/female counts for ALL users, but when I try to add either a filter or a contextual filter on user.created I get no results (and my brain goes flatline—see “extra credit”, below).

Is it possible (within Views) to do what I’m trying to do, and if so, how?

Extra credit: 4,000 brownie points for anyone who can help me understand why when you add a filter you specify aggregation rules.  When filtering, I'm thinking about constraining the results, not aggregating them.  What am I missing?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work-around -- http://drupal.org/node/847698#comment-3174900

Disable aggregation, then add filter, then re-enable aggregation.